# Can anyone explain all the attributes of "do action" in fusebox framework (coldfusion)

Tags: coldfusion, fusebox

Can anyone explain all the attributes of "do action" in **fusebox** framework (coldfusion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link is useful: http://www.dopefly.com/projects/fuseboxxmlcheatsheet.cfm

The documentation within /fusebox/circuit.dtd also has some explanation:

**action** Required. Defines the fuseaction to add to the Fuseaction queue. 
    Can be either a fully-qualified fuseaction (e.g. someCircuit.someFuseaction) 
    or another fuseaction in the same circuit (e.g. someOther).

**contentvariable** Optional. If a contentvariable name is specified, all the 
    output of the fuseaction in the action attribute will be saved to this 
    variable name.

**append** Optional, defaults to false. Determines whether output from the 
    fuseaction will be appended to (true) or overwrite (false) the 
    contentvariable specified in the contentvariable attribute.

**overwrite** Optional, defaults to true. If contentvariable is specified
    and this attribute is "false", the template is only included if 
    the specified contentvariable is not already defined.